# Origin and etymology of "travel"

Tags: etymology, verbs

Yesterday I was asking about the origin of the word *trabajo* ("work") in Spanish, that most etymologists think that comes from Latin *tripalium* (or *trepalium* according to other sources), an instrument of torture, and its verb *tripaliare*, "to torture". An English cognate is *travail*, that [according to the Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/travail) it still conveys the meaning of "agony, torment", while [the Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/travail) says it means a "painful or laborious effort".

Both dictionaries agree with its origin, but a note in the M-W also says:

> From *trepalium* sprang the Anglo-French verb *travailler*, which originally meant "to torment" but eventually acquired the milder senses "to trouble" and "to journey." The Anglo-French noun *travail* was borrowed into English in the 13th century, followed about a century later by *travel*, another descendant of travailler.

The Oxford dictionary seems to confirm that *travel* is a variant of *travail*. So it seems that the English verb *to travel* also derives from that original torment. The similarity of *travail* and *travel* is obvious, but how did a word that meant *torment* evolve its meaning into *journey*? Are there any texts that can confirm this and in which we can see this evolution?

Comment: "**travel (v.)**  late 14c., "to journey," from *travailen* (1300) "to make a journey," originally "to toil, labor" (see travail). The semantic development may have been via the notion of "go on a difficult journey," but it also may reflect the difficulty of any journey in the Middle Ages. Replaced Old English *faran*." https://www.etymonline.com/word/travel

Comment: @Kris thank you, your comment may as well be an answer. :-)

Comment: Nice to be of help. Here on ELU, answers that are available on easily accessible sources like various online sources are considered general reference. We are expected to try them first before asking a question here. So mine was only a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Kris you're right, I'm very used to use online resources in [Spanish.SE] but I still have to learn what's available for the English language. My bad.

Comment: Did you think to look on an etymology website like this one?: [link](https://www.etymonline.com/word/travel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRAVEL**

I have found a text that uses "travell" to mean "work", dating from 1576.

In the introduction to "[The Rocke of Regard](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pfdmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA2&dq=travel&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAisvV6-baAhViQZoKHZh0B4EQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=travel&f=false)" by George Whetstone, he uses the following passage:

> and further, for that I know the most part of youth (to whome I chiefly dedicate the fruite of my **travell**) are so carelesse of their commoditie, as they set light of sound advice, unless such persuasions be sauced (in some respect) with their owne desires...And yet, least they lighting on some discourse of worth, shoulde by and by be led away with the sight of some wanton devise, I have published my **travell** under these foure following titles.

At some point between 1579 and 1587 (these dates being the period when Sir Thomas Bromley was Lord Chancellor), "travel" is used for "journey", in the [Journals of the House of Lords](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZGTv_AWVHIkC&q=travel&dq=travel&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyu5yF8ObaAhXqKJoKHe2nD1k4ChDoAQgtMAE) (see 2nd snippet view).

> *Sir Thomas Bromley*, Knight, Lord Chancellor of *England*, is at this Time so visited with Sickness, that he is not able to **travel** to the Upper House of this Our present Parliament, holden at *Westm.*, nor there to supply the Room and Place in the said Upper House, among the Lords Spiritual and Temporal there assembled, as to the Office of the Lord Chancellor, or Lord Keeper of the Great Seal of *England*, hath been accustomed

**TRAVAIL**

If 1560 is early enough, one book alone contains several uses of "travail" meaning "work", and at least one where it means "make a journey".

[The Calendar of State Papers, Foreign Series, of the Reign of Elizabeth, 1559-1560](https://hdl.handle.net/2027/osu.32435062152947?urlappend=%3Bseq=508) contains this passage, dated Feb 12 1560, in which "travail" appears to cross the border from "work" to "journey":

> As for his keeping watch, he thinks the French in Leith and Inchkeith would not deny but that the fleet had kept them waking.  There has been never night since he came hither, being possible for men to **travail** upon the water, but that he has had 300 or 400 men armed in boats to guard the haven's mouth, that no succours should come in to them between the shore and the ships; and that they might not be able to put more men or victuals into Inchkieth.

A further [example, from Feb 19, 1560](https://hdl.handle.net/2027/osu.32435062152947?urlappend=%3Bseq=525), blurs the lines a little between the two meanings:

> Cecil considered that Sir James Croftes was the meetest for that purpose, from his experience amongst the Scots, and his **travail** taken in the discourse of the said journey;

There are several (over 30) other uses of "travail" to mean "work" in the same publication, [an example of which is below, from Feb 25, 1560](https://hdl.handle.net/2027/osu.32435062152947?urlappend=%3Bseq=541):

> Most heartily thanks him for his earnest **travail** about the said payment, and is right glad that it is so well ended.

Hence, it can be seen that travail was certainly used in the mid-late 16th Century to mean both work and journey, and that the same was also the case for "travel" a decade or two later.

Also, the hardship and difficulty of making any lengthy journey seems to be pertinent to the evolution from one meaning to the other.

Answer (score 0):

According to the OED the etymology of ***travel*** it is derived from the same word as ***travail*** v.

> 2a. intr. To make a journey; to go from one place to another; to
>   journey. Also fig.
>
> α.
>
> c1290   S. Eng. Leg. I. 25/61   For ȝe þus i-trauailede beoth fram
>   so ferre londe..Ich eov nelle greui nouȝt.
>
> c1330   R. Mannyng Chron. (1810) 3   He was of grete elde, & myght not
>   trauaile.
>
> 1413   Pilgr. Sowle (1859) i. i. 1   I had longe tyme trauayled toward
>   the holy Cyte of Ierusalem.
>
> 1544   Letanie in Exhort. vnto Prayer sig. Bviii   To preserue all
>   that trauaile by lande or by water.
>
> 1590   Spenser Faerie Queene i. ii. sig. B7   Long time they thus
>   together traueiled.
>
> a1616   Shakespeare Measure for Measure (1623) i. iii. 14   He
>   supposes me trauaild to Poland.    1691   J. Norris Pract. Disc.
>   Divine Subj. 94   Why should we..quit the Road they have taken, if we
>   may safely travail in it?
>
> 1714   J. Gay Shepherd's Week Proeme sig. A3   Other Poet travailing
>   in this plain High-way of Pastoral.
>
> β.
>
> c1410   Sir Cleges 16   To men, that traveld in londe of ware.
>
> c1480  (▸a1400)    St. Eugenia 326 in W. M. Metcalfe Legends Saints
>   Sc. Dial. (1896) II. 133   Sen scho mycht nocht trawel hym til.
>
> 1483   Cath. Angl. 391/2   To Travelle, itinerare.
>
> 1568  (▸a1500)    Freiris Berwik 39 in W. T. Ritchie Bannatyne MS
>   (1930) IV. 262   For he wes awld and micht not wele travell.
>
> 1594   T. Nashe Vnfortunate Traveller sig. L3   He is no body that
>   hath not traueld.
>
> a1616   Shakespeare As you like It (1623) i. iii. 108   What danger
>   will it be to vs,..to trauell forth so farre?    1697   Dryden tr.
>   Virgil Georgics iv, in tr. Virgil Wks. 126   A thirsty train That long
>   have travel'd through a desart plain.    1768   L. Sterne Sentimental
>   Journey I. 34   An English man does not travel to see English men.
>
> 1855   F. A. Paley Æschylus (1861) Pref. 28   They have..pointed out
>   the path in which succeeding editors should travel.
>
> 1901   W. R. H. Trowbridge Lett. Mother to Elizabeth iv. 13   [They]
>   travelled down from London in a special Pullman attached to the
>   Bristol express.

Comment: Note the observation "The semantic development may have been via the notion of "go on a difficult journey," but it also may reflect the difficulty of any journey in the Middle Ages." on etymonline.

Comment: But this only covers the start of the [metaphorical] journey, not the twists and turns along the way OP is asking about: '[H]ow did a word that meant _torment_ evolve its meaning into _journey_? Are there any texts that can confirm this and in which we can see this evolution?'